# Dotnet CLI webapi Project Build Failure - Error MSB3021

Tags: visual-studio-code, dotnet-cli, dotnet-sdk, dotnet-tool, dotnet-build

Machine: Windows 10.
SDK:  5.0.401
Project Type:  webapi

Issue:  Running `dotnet build` produces the following...
[image]

Things I've already tried:

- resmon.exe => to look for either the apphost.exe handle or the API.exe handle. None found.
- Reinstalled VS Code
- Reinstalled the SDK
- Completely erased the solution, keeping backup copies of the code, and re-creating it.

The funny thing is, that if I restart my machine, the issue goes away only to come back when I run `dotnet run` or `dotnet watch run`.

I'm afraid I'm not allowed to post any code/project structure, yet please let me know if there's anything else I can provide that would help out.

### Update

Here's the `dotnet --info` output:

```
$ dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.401
 Commit:    4bef5f3dbf

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19043
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.401\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.10
  Commit:  e1825b4928

.NET SDKs installed:
  1.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.700 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.701 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.818 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.119 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.200 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.207 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.303 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: you have permission to write to that path on the w drive?

Comment: Yes. My user account is a member of the Administrators group, and this group is set as the owner of "<ProjectFolder>\bin\Debug\net5.0"...which is even crazier.  However my impression is the same as  yours:  there has to be a permissions issue preventing the action.  I've confirmed this by manually creating a .txt file inside that folder (with success) and then attempting to rename it to "API.exe" (which fails indicating that I must have administrator access to perform that action).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the culprit:  AVG Antivirus update.

Visited the quarantine container and almost lost my jaw after looking at the humongous list of .exe files in there. An exception rule solved the problem on my end.